# Como fazer um arquivo redirecionar para outro?

Tags: html, http

Uma página HTTPS minha está exigindo que eu apenas faça link para recursos HTTPS. Caso contrário aparecem mensagens de aviso pro usuário. Eu queria que fosse possível baixar um arquivo do site, sem aparecer nenhuma mensagem de aviso pro usuário. Só que eu preciso guardar o arquivo em outro local que só serve HTTP. Será que tem como criar um arquivo no servidor HTTPS que redirecione o download pra ser baixado do servidor HTTP?

Comment: O que você está se referindo é colocar um arquivo em um servidor HTTP e carregar-lo usando um <script> em uma página https? Se for um download normal não aconteceria nenhum erro.

Comment: É obrigação do navegador me avisar quando estou numa conexão segura e o site me redireciona ou tenta incluir algo não seguro. Não tente burlar a segurança. Ao invés disso, inclua os recursos desejados numa conexão segura também.

Comment: On Chrome: '[blocked] The page at 'https://.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://.com/': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.'

Comment: @utluiz Estou testando no aqui e nenhum navegador está dando esse alerta para downloads, só para script. Depois desse último comentário do #jader-dias parece que ele se refere mesmo a um script: faça o que o #utluiz disse.

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues não tem script envolvido. Suas configurações de segurança devem estar mais relaxadas que a minha. Eu tenho o "HTTPS Everywhere" mas não está ativo. Acho que o problema são as Group Policies da minha empresa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução é simples.
No link que vai abrir o arquivo, use target="_blank"

```
<a href="aqruivo.xxx" target="_blank">download</a>
```

Comment: isso é pra abrir em outra aba, não pra redirecionar o download

Comment: @JaderDias se você quer que o download aconteça fora do HTTPS, terá de iniciar outra janela, não tem jeito.